# Загрузка музыкальных файлов на сервер: ограничение по типам при загрузке

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. 
Есть код который позволяет загрузить на сервер только изображения.

```
$imgDir = dirname(__FILE__)."/gallery/$us[users_login]/";
@mkdir($imgDir, 0777);

if (@$_REQUEST['doUpload']) { 
$data = $_FILES['file']; 
$tmp = $data['tmp_name']; 
if (@file_exists($tmp)) { 
$info = @getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); 
if (preg_match('{image/(.*)}is', $info['mime'], $p)) { 
  $name = "$imgDir/".time().".".$p[1]; 
  move_uploaded_file($tmp, $name);
  $times = time(); 
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO photo_gallery SET id_us='".$us['users_id']."', time='".$times."', name_foto='".$times."', ras='".$p[1]."', id_album='".$alb['id']."'");
  header("Location: /photo_album.go?id=$alb[id]&us=$us[users_id]");
} else { 
  echo "<div class='list'>Данный тип файла запрещен для загрузки!</div>"; 
} 
} else { 
echo "<div class='list'>Упс. Ошибка!</div>"; 
} 
}
```

а мне нужно чтобы можно было загрузить только музыкальные файлы: mp3, wav и т.п. ну или хотя бы mp3 только.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно делать проверку на MIME тип файла

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
$array_types = array(
    'audio/mp4' => true,
    'audio/ogg' => true,
);
if(isset($array_types[$mime])){
    // выполняем загрузку файла
}
```

Подробнее про функцию почитать можно [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.finfo-file.php), а полный список MIME типов [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_MIME-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2)

**Внесение изменения в текущий код**

```
$imgDir = dirname(__FILE__)."/gallery/$us[users_login]/";
@mkdir($imgDir, 0777);

if (@$_REQUEST['doUpload']) { 
$data = $_FILES['file']; 
$tmp = $data['tmp_name']; 
if (@file_exists($tmp)) {
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $tmp);
    $array_types = array(
        'audio/mp4' => true,
        'audio/ogg' => true,
    );
    if(isset($array_types[$mime])){ 
        $name = "$imgDir/".time().".".$p[1]; 
        move_uploaded_file($tmp, $name);
        $times = time(); 
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO photo_gallery SET id_us='".$us['users_id']."', time='".$times."', name_foto='".$times."', ras='".$p[1]."', id_album='".$alb['id']."'");
        header("Location: /photo_album.go?id=$alb[id]&us=$us[users_id]");
    } else { 
        echo "<div class='list'>Данный тип файла запрещен для загрузки!</div>"; 
    } 
} else { 
    echo "<div class='list'>Упс. Ошибка!</div>"; 
} 
}
```

Писал на коленке, и может не будет работать, но идея вот такая.

Типы указывать здесь

```
$array_types = array(
    'audio/mp4' => true,
    'audio/ogg' => true,
);
```

Comment: не моли бы вы внести поправку с учетом вашего кода в мой код чтобы он разрешал загружать mp3, я просто не совсем понял

Comment: этот код вообще не чего не позволяет загрузить